# Make it possible to download .rtf file

Tags: http, header, content-type

I am able to make the pdf file downloadable when the use clicks the download link. For this I did like this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (!reader.Read()) return;
                Response.Clear();

                string fileExtension = reader["FileExt"].ToString().Trim();

                if (reader["DocumentData"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    switch (fileExtension)
                    case "pdf":
                            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                            break;
                            ...

                    case "rtf":
                            Response.ContentType = "application/rtf";
                            break;
```

I tried to do the same for the .rtf, but when the user clicks the link the browser instead shows the image I attached below (weird symbols). But I want it to promt the user to save the file. I the user right clicks on the link, and says save as (someName.rtf), then it works fine. But the old generation of people will not know this.

[image]
I tried with

```
application/rtf
application/x-rtf
text/richtext
```

Most of the examples I found use `application/rtf`

Is there something else I need to do, so that people can download the .rtf files?
I have tried to provide the relevant code, but please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had someone who has experience with PHP to help me. My solution was to add this:

```
case "rtf":
                            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                            Response.Headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "Binary";
                            Response.Headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"fileName.rtf\"";

                            break;
```

So I force the browser to download the file, instead of trying to render it.
I hope this will save someone for the same amount of time that I used.